# Workflow Foundation - VB expression editor

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, workflow-foundation, workflow-activity

I need to force the VB expression editor on my activities in order to allow them to be rehosted. When I create them in a C# project they default to C# expression editor. How can I force the VB expression editor on all new activities?